# How can I fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named gdal' when trying to import the gdal module in Visual Studio Code using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

**gdal is not imported**

I have installed GDAL with Conda and it is available in the Conda list. However, when I try to import gdal in Visual Studio Code (Python file), I get the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'`.

I am a beginner in Python and would appreciate any simple methods to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Does Visual Studio Code use the same python environment as conda?

Comment: I think yes, I set these options using Ctrl+Shift+P

Comment: ...  `pip install` to the correct python is the most likely reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using `import gdal` isn't supported anymore since quite some time. Please use `from osgeo import gdal`