# In Google Collab GDAL library is pre installed though when I am running "import gdal" I am facing an error "No Module" found

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory, gdal

[When I have tried to use gdal I have tried installing gdal library and then trying to import it still facing problem of No Module Error in Google collab Use of GDAL library facing problem to import it shows me the error of No Module found I also had tried this in Jupyter Notebook and Also using Conda Environment [The problem I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4itA0.png)]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe you have to use `pip3` instead of `pip` - to install module for correct Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named gdal' when trying to import the gdal module in Visual Studio Code using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362671/how-can-i-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gdal-when-trying-to-import)